# jQuery multiple inputs with one Function RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I've got a form with more than 1 inputfields. The format that should be allowed is hh:mm / h:mm. So I already have a function, that checks my input if the format is true inbstandly on input.

So what I want is, if i click on my submit button i'd like to check all the boxes again if the format is right. If true then submit(); else then alert() or something. But that isnt the problmem.

I have no idea how i can realize this. Thank you in advance :))

```
function validateAbs(inputField) {

                var isValid = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/.test(inputField.value);    
                if (isValid) {
                    inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#bfa';
                } else {
                    inputField.style.backgroundColor = '#fba';
                }

                return isValid;
            }



            $(function(){
                $('#ist').on('input', function() {
                    //This is one of ne hh:mm Textboxes
                    validateAbs(this);
                });
             });

             $(function(){
                $('#abssubmit').on('input', function() {
                    //This is my Submit-Button
                });
             });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's surprisingly easy:

```
$('#abssubmit').on('input', function() {
    $("selector-for-the-inputs-you-want-to-check").each(function() {
        validateAbs(this);
    });
});
```

If you want to know whether any of them is invalid, you can use `filter`:

```
$('#abssubmit').on('input', function() {
    var invalidFields = $("selector-for-the-inputs-you-want-to-check").filter(function() {
        return !validateAbs(this);
    });
    if (invalidFields.length) {
        // At least one field was invalid
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! :D Thank you! But I have still a Problem.
If there are 3 Boxes
1st Box: 2:14
2nd Box: empty
3rd Box: 14:12

I got true, false, true. Can you tell me how i can combine them so its false. But when every Box ist correct than true? :)

Comment: @PasiB: That's the second part of the answer above, with `filter`. E.g., `!invalidFields.length` will be `true` if they're all valid, `false` if any of them was invalid.

Comment: Yes I typed it without refreshing the page before.

Great thank you! It works! :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change to a submit handler not an 'input' handler:

```
$('#abssubmit').on('submit', function(ev) {
    var isValid;
    ev.preventDefault(); // to stop the form from submitting
    $('#ist').each(function() {
        if (!validateAbs(this)) isValid = false;
    });
    if (isValid) {
        this.submit(); // all the validations succeeded
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, i copied it wrong. But your solution works for me! Thanks!